# Customer login only working in private browsing

Tags: magento2, cache, login

When a customer tries to login to his account, it redirects right back to the login screen. The text on top changes to way "Welcome, ", but the customer can't actually see anything in his account.

Any reason this could be happening? I've cleared and restarted all caches quite a few times, but always with the same result.

Comment: Have you install any third party extension for the customer related functionality? Try to disable and check.

Comment: Trying that with Mageplaza Login for pricing

Comment: clear  the cookie in your browser for  the specific site and  try to login again . Alternatively open your website in different browser which you  do  not use before ..

Comment: Tried that. I both cleared the cookies, and tried multiple browsers. Same thing. Whatever the problem is, i'ts not coming from the "Login for pricing" plugin

Comment: try with remove all browser cache

Comment: Check your cookie lifetime in Store->Configuration->General->Web->Default cookie settings. BBy default you get 3600. you can increase it to 86400. Set ```Cookie Restriction Mode``` to ```no```. ```HTTP Only``` to ```yes```.

Comment: @sebastianT Thanks, changing the cookie lifetime. Do I need to set the cookie domain and/or path?

Comment: @SebastianT also, please change your comment to an answer. Changing the cookie lifetime fixed my issue, and I'd like to be able to accept it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @webmaster glad to hear, that you solved your problem :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your cookie lifetime in `Store->Configuration->General->Web->Default cookie settings`. By default you have `3600` (one hour). You can increase it to `86400`(one day). Set `Cookie Restriction Mode` to **no**. `HTTP Only` to **yes**.

About `domain` and `path`. Here you have one helpful link : [Helpful link](https://belvg.com/blog/cookies-in-magento-2-0.html), because i'm not an expert in cookies settings :D